# Android : Layout Animation parallel in Property Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want an animation to be applied to all the child items of a grid layout. This animation should run as soon as the activity becomes visible and should be applied to grid's children one after the other.

I know I can use [Grid Layout Animation Controller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html). I want to know if there is a better solution to this in Property Animation API. As this API gives more flexibility while animating. Or should i dynamically add animations to all my grid items and start the animation as soon as the view is visible??